# Setting collation in "az sql db create" fails

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cli

It appears it is not possible to set the collation when creating an Azure SQL Server as follows:

```
az sql db create `
    --name $sqlDatabaseName `
    --server $sqlServerName `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --edition Basic `
    --collation "Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8"
```

The error message tells "az : az: error: unrecognized arguments: -–collation Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8".

But as not being well versed with Azure CLI, it occurred to ask if there's another way to pass this value when creating the database? Or do I need to update it afterwards?

My Azure CLI version is 2.9.1. I have tried with and without quotes and with and without prefixing the collation with `SQL_`. Using the management portal it shows this particular collation is accepted. I see  that if I comment the collation the default one has `SQL_` prefixed to it.

<edit: This is edited like given in the answer and it works now. What a typo to have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code `az sql db create`  and get the same error:

```
az : az: error: unrecognized arguments: -–collation Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8
```

You have the character error in your command `-–collation "Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8"`:

[image]

Please edit it with `--`:

```
az sql db create `
    --name $sqlDatabaseName `
    --server $sqlServerName `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --edition Basic `
    --collation "Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8"
```

Comment: Hah! Exactly right. What a typo to have there. I need a different editor or font for midnight programming apparently!